# Object does not match target type when trying to get property from IEnumerable<TRes> which result of Func<T,TRes> .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, reflection

What I'm trying to get is a property from an entity and sum the values.  I'm using generics and the type of the entity and the name of the property are known at run time. The following (simplified) code compiles fine but throws "Object does not match target type." when trying to get the property from the entity.  Here is the code:

```
    public class SomeModel
    {
        public int ValueA { get; set; }
        public int ValueB { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public int ViewValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<SomeModel> data = GetData();

            var result = SumValues(data, a => new SomeViewModel { ViewValue = a.ValueA });

            return Content(string.Format("Total is: {0}", result));
        }

        private int SumValues<T, TRes>(IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, TRes> transformation)
        {
            var transformedData = data.Select(transformation);
            Type type = typeof(TRes);
            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("ViewValue");
            IEnumerable<int> listOfValues = property.GetValue(transformedData, null) as IEnumerable<int>;
            var sum = listOfValues.Sum();

            return sum;
        }

        private IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetData()
        {
            var data = new List<SomeModel>();
            Random random;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                random = new Random(i);
                data.Add(new SomeModel { ValueA = random.Next(5,100), ValueB = random.Next(20,80) });
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
```

I'm generating fake data here, but the real application is bringing data from database using EF.  Generics is new to me so please any advice pointing me on the right direction will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
IEnumerable<int> listOfValues = 
                       property.GetValue(transformedData, null) as IEnumerable<int>;
```

You're trying to retrieve the value of the `ViewValue` property on a `List<SomeModel>` object, but `List<SomeModel>` doesn't have a `ViewValue` property. One thing you could do is this:

```
IEnumerable<int> listOfValues = 
                       transformedData.Select(i => (int)property.GetValue(i, null));
```

But a much cleaner solution would be to avoid reflection entirely as it's not needed here:

```
interface IViewValue
{
    int ViewValue { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewModel : IViewValue
{
    public int ViewValue { get; set; }
}

private int SumValues<T, TRes>(IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, TRes> transformation)
                                            where TRes : IViewValue
{
    var transformedData = data.Select(transformation);
    IEnumerable<int> listOfValues = transformedData.Select(i => i.ViewValue);
    var sum = listOfValues.Sum();

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you for answering so quickly.  Both options are working fine.  I end up using the first one since the property names can be anything just decorated with a flag indicating that a total is required for it. Thank you again.